# Shouldn't I use axios in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

In the meantime, I've been using axios to fetch data comfortably. When I moved to Next.js, I realized that axios doesn't allow caching, so when multiple components fetch the same URL, they request a lot of data. I think I should use fetch, but fetch is inconvenient. I don't like the idea of changing to json and having to specify the return type and the header. Do you use fetch instead of axios when using Next.js in practice? I'm curious to know how practicing developers fetch data.  Please let me know your thoughts

And if I use fetch, I think I don't need to use react-query because of caching...what do you use in practice?

Answer (score 0):

I use RTK Query for data fetching and `fetch` for some places. But I create a custom fetcher function and use that like bellow

```
export default async function fetcher(
  endpoint,
  {token, body, ...customConfig} = {}
) {
  const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

  if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
  }

  const config = {
    method: body ? 'POST' : 'GET',
    ...customConfig,
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      ...customConfig.headers,
    },
  }

  if (body) {
    config.body = JSON.stringify(body)
  }

  let response
  try {
    response = await fetch(endpoint, config)
    if (response?.ok) {
      return await response.json()
    }

    throw new Error('Server returned ' + response.status)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('There was a problem with the Fetch operation,', error)
    return null
  }
}
```

And use that fetcher function like that

```
try {
  const {data: response} = await fetcher(endpoint)

  if (response.status === 200) {
    return response
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log('========================================')
  console.error('error in function name', error)
  console.log('========================================')
  return {}
}
```

If you plan to use fetch, you should make your custom fetcher function and use that instead of using typical use of fetch. Hope you will get a idea.

Comment: Thanks!
I only use the GET and POST methods, but the DELETE and PATCH methods are not used in practice?

Comment: @pvp11 yes, you can use DELETE, PATCH, PUT methods also like this `fetcher(endpoint, {method: 'DELETE'})`. If you pass attributes with `customConfig`, it will override respective  default configuration.